# OS X 10.6.8 cannot log into domain after creating local user account

Tags: macos, user-accounts

I added a Mac with OS X 10.6.8 to our company Windows Domain. I was able to log into the domain without any problems. I'm new to Macs so I made the mistake of creating a local account with the same user name but it never actually created the user that I can see. It froze up and I had to manually power down.

Now when I try to log into the domain with the same credentials, the screen just shakes. I can log in as other domain users fine. I tried to create the local account again and it says that the user name is already used.

Is there a command maybe that can completely wipe out a profile like it was never there. Any help on this would be much appreciated because I have to get this user setup ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Does the account show up in the Users pane in System Preferences? You should be able to delete it there. If it's not showing up, delete the corresponding user folder from the /Users directory.

If there's no user folder, you'll need to use the dscl command. Run this command (be very careful!):

> sudo dscl . delete /users/username

Where username is the shortname of the user that you'd like to delete.